# How to simplify the following distance function for the taxicab ring metric space?

Tags: haskell, mathematics

Consider the taxicab ring metric space shown below. This is a discrete metric space in which we have both a grid and concentric diamond rings. This metric space stretches infinitely in all four directions, but I have only drawn four rings.

I want to write a function that returns the shortest distance between any two points in this metric space. Obviously, the shortest distance must be lesser than or equal to the [taxicab distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) because sometimes we can take the diagonal shortcuts. For example, the taxicab distance between (2,-1) and (3,1) is 3. However, we can reduce this to 2 when we follow the diagonal shortcut from (2,-1) to (3,0). Similarly, the taxicab distance between (2,-1) and (-1,3) is 7. However, we can reduce this to 5 when we follow the diagonal shortcut from (2,0) to (0,2).

[image: Taxicab Ring Metric Space]

So, here's the function that I came up with in Haskell. It computes the taxicab distance and then subtracts the diagonal shortcut distance to get the final result. The shortcut distance is calculated in one to three steps. First, we translate and rotate p2 such that p1 is at the origin. This is so that we don't repeat ourselves by duplicating code for each of the four quadrants. If the new p2 is in the upper right quadrant then the shortcut distance is 0 because we're moving in a line perpendicular to the diagonal.

If the new p2 is in the upper left or the lower right quadrants then we are moving parallel to the diagonal. Hence, we can compute the shortcut distance accordingly. It's the minimum of the difference in x and y coordinates and the corresponding absolute coordinate of p1, i.e. x1 for upper left quadrant and y1 for the lower right quadrant.

Finally, if the new p2 is in the lower left quadrant then we take advantage of [symmetric property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function) of distance functions to perform the above steps again with p1 and p2 swapped. If both p1 and p2 are in opposite quadrants then we'll eventually call the `opposite` function. Now, there are two paths to get from p1 to p2. Either we go down first and then left or vice versa. Hence, we compute the shortcut distance for both and then select the one which is greater.

```hs
type Coord = (Integer, Integer)

type Metric = Coord -> Coord -> Integer

dist :: Metric
dist p1@(x1, y1) p2@(x2, y2) = abs (x2 - x1) + abs (y2 - y1) - diag p1 p2

diag :: Metric
diag = adjacent (adjacent opposite)

adjacent :: Metric -> Metric
adjacent metric p1@(x1, y1) p2@(x2, y2)
    | x >= 0 && y >= 0 = 0
    | x <= 0 && y >= 0 = minimum [abs x, abs y, abs x1]
    | x >= 0 && y <= 0 = minimum [abs x, abs y, abs y1]
    | otherwise        = metric p2 p1
    where
        x = if x1 < 0 then x1 - x2 else if x1 > 0 then x2 - x1 else abs x2
        y = if y1 < 0 then y1 - y2 else if y1 > 0 then y2 - y1 else abs y2

opposite :: Metric
opposite (x1, y1) (x2, y2) =
    max (minimum [abs (x2 - x1), abs x1, abs y2])
        (minimum [abs (y2 - y1), abs x2, abs y1])
```

Anyway, is it possible to simplify the above distance function? For example, `diag` is currently defined as the application of an [iterated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) to another function. Can we get rid of this without duplicating code? Alternatively, is it possible to replace the call to `diag` with a [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)? The `diag` function is quite complex. Is it possible to simplify it?